# Understanding the localization of a module

Tags: ring-theory, modules, localization

When I first came across the concept of the *localization of a ring*, my immediate reaction upon reading the definition was one of "Well, why is it called the *localization* of a ring? Wouldn't the *fractionalization* of a ring be a far more appropriate term?"

Fortunately, I came across the definition in the context of classical algebraic geometry, and it didn't take me long after reading what followed in the texts I were consulting to understand that, ah yes, if $R$ is the coordinate ring of some algebraic set $V$, then a localization of $R$ to some multiplicatively closed subset corresponds to the restriction of $R$ to some open subset of $V$, and the whole "we are looking at the same ring as before, but in a *local setting*" became apparent to me.

My question today concerns the *localization of **modules***. Specifically, what is the analogous way of thinking of localizations of modules so that it becomes apparent that we are looking at the same module as before, but in a *local setting*?

Look forward to your answers!

Answer (score 4):

From the geometric point of view, modules $M$ over a ring $R$ correspond to quasicoherent sheaves on the spectrum $S$ of the ring, which are something like generalized vector bundles $E\to S$. Given such a bundle, one can recover the module as the global sections $\hom_S(S,E)$ of the bundle.  Moreover, if $r\in R$ is an element such that the localization $R_r$ corresponds to an open subset $U\subset S$, then the localization $M_r$ is the $R_r$-module of global sections of the restricted bundle $E\vert_U\to U$ that is obtained by taking the inverse image of $U$ along the projection $E\to S$.